# Bypass certificate using .Net HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to post a REST message to a website that has a certificate problem. Until our IT guy can resolve it, I need to bypass this when executing the 
`PostAsync` call.

For some reason the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` is no longer part of the `HttpClientHandler`. Is there a another approach to resolve 
this to avoid the permissions error? Thanks.

Here's a sample of what I'm doing.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Message = new
                {
                    TestID = "1",
                }
            });


var spHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        return true;
    }
};

System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(spHandler,true);
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://test.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage msg = client.PostAsync(@"/Test", content).Result;
```

Edited: (Fix '/' delimiter issue)

From

```
 client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://test.com");
 HttpResponseMessage msg = client.PostAsync(@"/Test", content).Result;
```

To

```
 client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://test.com/");
 HttpResponseMessage msg = client.PostAsync("Test", content).Result;
```

Comment: new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler,true) or  new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(spHandler,true) ?

Comment: It's supposed to be System.Net.Http.HttpClient(spHandler,true). I've just been trying a bunch of approaches and forgot to change it back. I updated the question.

Comment: What .NET you are using? Core or Full?

Comment: I'm using the .NET Framework.

Comment: The posted code works fine...

Comment: If you found the cause, write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem and edited the question above. Turns out you cant use a leading '/' on the uri PostAsync query. This was causing the problem. The handler was actually fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was successfully bypassed certificate validation by the following steps:

1. Get the certificate
   X509Certificate2 clientCert = GetClientCertificate();
2. Create request handler and pass the certificate

   WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
               requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);
3. Call the handler

   System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                   delegate { return true; };
4. Create HttpClient object passing the handler and call the service.

   HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)

I hope this is useful for you.